# Handling object with keys correctly on ForEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I have this object, where I am using forEach method to loop thru the key values and display the object content in a table. Currently, it works fine, but if i try to alter the keys name array, the forEach loop will break:

```
let response = [{
  "rule.id": 222222,
  "rule.name": "Test Name",
  "rule.compiledlimitation": "Sampel Data",
  "rule.target": "TEST_ID",
}]

let keys = ["id", 'name', "compiledlimitation", 'target']

keys.forEach(key => {
  this.allData.push({
    name: key,
    row2: response[0][`rule.${key}`]
  })
});
```

The problem happens when i try to modify the keys values, For example if i want to enter ID as caps, or name as 'Name', or compiledlimitations as 'Compiled Limitations' then my loop will break because it doesn't match the object name.

This is how the table looks if i alter the keys name, the value is empty :(
[image]

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: Why are you modifying the `keys` value to something that doesn't match the object?

Comment: It's to show the key with capital letters, spaces between words in the UI table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just extend your `keys` array and bind a custom `label` to each `key`:

```js
let response = [
  {
    'rule.id': 222222,
    'rule.name': 'Test Name',
    'rule.compiledlimitation': 'Sampel Data',
    'rule.target': 'TEST_ID',
  },
];

let keys = [
  { key: 'id', label: 'ID' },
  { key: 'name', label: 'Name' },
  { key: 'compiledlimitation', label: 'Compiled Limitation' },
  { key: 'target', label: 'Target' },
];

allData = [];

keys.forEach(({ key, label }) => {
  allData.push({
    name: label, // use the label that will get displayed
    row2: response[0][`rule.${key}`], // use the key to get the info
  });
});

console.log(allData);
```

Comment: Thank you, this covers my use cases!

Comment: labels comes in handy here :)

Answer (score 2):

Change `keys` to be an array of objects that contains both the displayed labels and the object keys.

```js
let response = [{
  "rule.id": 222222,
  "rule.name": "Test Name",
  "rule.compiledlimitation": "Sampel Data",
  "rule.target": "TEST_ID",
}];

const keys = [{
  key: "id",
  label: "ID"
}, {
  key: 'name',
  label: 'Name'
}, {
  key: "compiledlimitation",
  label: "Compiled Limitation"
}, {
  key: 'target',
  label: 'Target'
}];

let allData = keys.map(({key, label}) => ({
  name: label,
  row2: response[0][`rule.${key}`]
}));

console.log(allData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If response keys are always in lowercase, then you could use the following:

```
response[0][`rule.${key.toLowerCase()}`]
```

Or even better to normalize the keys before accessing the response properties i.e.

```
keys = keys.map((key) => key.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extra variable that maps your `keys` to the keys in the object. And make it such that it takes the original key by default. For instance in the example below, `keyMap` is the map variable and `Name` and `changedCompiledlimitation` are the two keys changed.

```js
const response = [{
  "rule.id": 222222,
  "rule.name": "Test Name",
  "rule.compiledlimitation": "Sampel Data",
  "rule.target": "TEST_ID",
}]

const keys = ["id", 'Name', "changedCompiledlimitation", 'target']
const keyMap = {
  Name: "name",
  changedCompiledlimitation: "compiledlimitation", 
};

const allData = [];
keys.forEach(key => {
  const keyInResponse = keyMap[key] || key;
  allData.push({
    name: key,
    row2: response[0][`rule.${keyInResponse}`]
  })
});

console.log(allData)
```